# Spivak's Chapter 5 Exercise 15 part xi

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

This problem is just a collection of limits to solve in terms of
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}{\frac{\sin(x)}x}= \alpha$$

Now i solved all of them except for the last one, which is:
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow1}\left((x^2-1)^3\sin\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^3\right)$$
I tried different factoring the expression but i just couldn't.
So I went to the solutions manual and I just got more confused.

[image]

First of all, I think there's a mistake, because $$ \left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^3\right| \leq 1$$
is true even for $x = 0$, so i guess he meant  for all $x \neq 1 $
But even then I don't quite get what he is doing. I graphed the function and indeed
It seems like $x$ approaches $0$.
However I just don't see why $ \left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^3\right| \leq 1$ would imply that. I wonder if it's anything like the $\epsilon ,\delta$ proofs that he gave before with $x\sin(1/x)$, so in this case, i would have to find some $\delta$ which guarantees $$|(x^2-1)^3| \leq \epsilon$$ if $0<|x-1|<\delta$

I didn't continue that idea because it seemed so long but if that's the only solution i guess i will have to do it. Is there any other way? Can you tell me why Spivak just gives that argument and calls it done?
Thank you for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=0$ and $g(x)$ is bounded in some deleted neighborhood of $c$ (this means that we exclude $x=c$ from the neighborhood), then $\lim_{x\to c}\left(f(x)g(x)\right)=0$.

Spivak is using this fact for $c=1$, $f(x)=(x^2-1)^3\to 0$ as $x\to 1$, and $g(x)=\sin\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^3$ which is in fact bounded everywhere except at $x=1$: $|g(x)|\leq 1$. And you're right about the typo. It should be $x\ne 1$.

For a proof, you can use the squeeze theorem (you can also try an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof). There is a neighborhood of $c$ and a positive number $M$ such that $|g(x)|\leq M$ for $x$ in that neighborhood. Then $|f(x)g(x)|\leq M|f(x)|$. Since $f(x)\to 0$, it follows by the squeeze theorem that $|f(x)g(x)|\to 0$ which implies that $f(x)g(x)\to 0$.

Comment: Well this seems reasonable, thanks so much. I think this 'theorem' was not mentioned previously, so it's so rare this shows up so spontaneously

Comment: I'm so sorry , I just checked and I actually proved this on a previous exercise, I thought it was cool but didn't really think about it. Now I see how it's used!!

Comment: @PacoAntonio I would greatly appreciate if you shared your proof.

Comment: It's the squeeze theorem, as bjorn93 said.He gave a proof in the last lines of his comment.